# Make Windows toolbar flat (not gradient color)

Tags: c++, winapi

C++ project, CodeLite, Win7. It shows toolbar which looks as gradient

[image: toolb]

I want to make it flat, so look is not like "blue gradient" like now but flat color (color of button face). How to do it?
Bar is created with code:

```
const TBBUTTON defaultButtons[] = {
//iBitmap, idCommand, fsState, fsStyle, dwData, iString
{ IDB_BITMAP_CONNECT, IDB_BUTTON_TOOLBAR_CONNECT, 0, TBSTYLE_DROPDOWN, {0,0}, 0, 0},
//IDB_BITMAP_DISCONNECT
{ 0, 0, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_SEP, {0,0}, 0, 0},
{ IDB_BITMAP_DOWNLOAD, IDB_BUTTON_TOOLBAR_DOWNLOAD, 0, BTNS_BUTTON, {0,0}, 0, 0},
{ IDB_BITMAP_UPLOAD, IDB_BUTTON_TOOLBAR_UPLOAD, 0, BTNS_BUTTON, {0,0}, 0, 0},
```

...

```
Toolbar::Toolbar() :
    Window(NULL, TOOLBARCLASSNAME),
    m_nrButtons(0),
    m_buttons(NULL),
    m_buttonMenus(NULL),
    m_connectBitmapIndex(-1),
    m_disconnectBitmapIndex(-1),
    m_rebar(NULL)
{
    m_exStyle = WS_EX_PALETTEWINDOW;
    m_style = WS_CHILD|/*WS_VISIBLE|*/WS_CLIPCHILDREN|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS|TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS|CCS_TOP|TBSTYLE_FLAT|BTNS_AUTOSIZE|CCS_NOPARENTALIGN|CCS_NORESIZE|CCS_NODIVIDER;
}
```

Comment: Use `SetWindowTheme` to disable the visual style for the toolbar.

Comment: Thks, +100 points to Slizerin =)